# Is it possible to use formula to find maximum value in array above and below skip selected cell (in the middle)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to do this using formula, given that the selected isn't fixed to specific cell, but could be anywhere in the column?

*Update More details
and this is not 1 time selection, the selection process keep occurring while after we got the maximum, the number will be +1 and put in that selection cell.

Then repeating this process for the next selections.

Or any alternative suggestions, please?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: so you want to select a cell and it not be considered?  Or is it that we need to ignore blanks?

Comment: Off the top of my head you could use a helper column to count blank rows so you can define the groups for which you want to find the max value. This will give you 0 for the first group, 1 for the 2nd group, 2 for the 3rd group... =COUNTIF(A$1:A100, ""). Then if you have filter() available in your version of Excel it would be simple to filter on the groups and get a max value. Otherwise it will be a little more complicated.

Comment: can you please confirm the desired outcome of your example is number `07` from Cell A3?

Comment: @TerryW that's correct, 07 is the outcome. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottCraner I want to select a cell and it not be considered. Thank you.

Comment: You will need vba. Formula cannot tell what is selected.

Comment: @DavidRichardson I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your first approach and for the filter this is quite interesting, can you explain a bit more about this filter(), please?

where do I put it? in the helper column? my next thought will be

Comment: @DavidRichardson I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your first approach and for the filter this is quite interesting, can you explain a bit more about this filter(), please?

where do I put it? in the helper column? 
I may be didn't explain it every clear, my apology,
for example
If I filter the max from current and got 07 (then I would plus 1) and I want to put 08 into A4?

and after I put 08 in A4 and I may be move on to select A10 for example, how do I repeat the same thing all over again? It will have circular error, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ceecee You could use FILTER() to filter the groups of rows. For example, if you use COUNTIF() as I described above, you could get all the values in A5:A8 by using FILTER(A:A, B:B = 1). Then do whatever you need to that filtered array. I'm happy to help, but you need to put in some effort. Determine if FILTER() is available to you and read up on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using FILTER which I don't really like. It uses brute force and seems inelegant. I'm sure there's a better solution.

[image]

First, create a helper column to group your items:

```
=IF(A2 = "", "", COUNTIF(A$2:A2, "") + 1)
```

Add the COUNTIF() to B2:B14. The IF() around the COUNTF() just tells it to return a blank string if it's on a row with nothing in Ax. I'm using +1 with the COUNTIF() results because filter doesn't work with 0. (#%^@! Excel can't differentiate between an empty cell and a cell with 0 in it. How can this possibly be? It be.)

Now add another helper column in C to get the numeric part of whatever is in Ax:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2, 2, 50))
```

This gets everything after the first character from Ax and turns it into a number. This is me being lazy - it's far easier to get the max of a number than a string in Excel.

So now you have your items grouped with a group ID in Col B and the numeric part of A2:A14 in C2:C14. Now we can use FILTER() to get the max value from each group.

```
MAX(FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2))
```

This will return 7. It's filtering C2:C14 based on the value of B2 and the values in B2:B14. That's good, but 7 isn't what we want. We want A07. So we can wrap an XLOOKUP() around it (or another lookup function) to find the corresponding value in Col A:

```
XLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2)), FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2), FILTER(A2:A14, B2:B14 = B2)))
```

This is a little uglier. We the first FILTER() with MAX() tells XLOOKUP() what value we're looking for. The 2nd filter tells XLOOKUP() where we want to search for that value: B:B where it equals the value in B2. The last filter tells XLOOKUP() where to get the return value, which is column A.

It's easier to display the results on the last row of each group, but it could be displayed in the gaps between groups as well. To display max value of a group of items in Col A, we can add this IF() in front of the XLOOKUP():

```
IF(OR(B3 = B2, B2 = ""), "", XLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2)), FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2), FILTER(A2:A14, B2:B14 = B2)))
```

The IF() compares the current row value of B to the next row value of B to see if they're in the same group. When they're not in the same group that must be the the last row. We also OR() that with a check for blank rows so we don't display the result in blank rows as well.

Rather than using MAX(), you can use the function below to get the max value from a group of text items:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(A2:A4,">"& A2:A4)=0), A2:A4)
```

That's not my solution. It's clever and works well. In this case it was easier to illustrate using MAX().

If you don't have access to FILTER() it will take some other array trickery to get this working. Hoping you have a version with FILTER().

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time and helping on this, I have read it twice but still need some more time to digest the information.

Comment: I think it will only go 80% of what need to be done and to achieved 100% I probably need to use VBA.

Because after I got what I need (the MAX) I want Excel to automatically put MAX + 1 into the selected cell, thinking over and over can't find solution using formula.

Comment: If the max in column A is A07 for a group, you want the output to be A08? If so, change the max function to be this: LEFT(XLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2)), FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2), FILTER(A2:A14, B2:B14 = B2))), 2) & RIGHT("0" & MAX(FILTER(C2:C14, B2:B14 = B2)) + 1, 2). This gets the left two characters from the whatever is the max string and, then increases the number at the end by 1. This assumes the there will only be two Alpha characters on the left and a 2 digit number on the right.

Comment: thank you! and how do I to automatically put the result in the selected cell? for example if I select A5, it is automatically put A08 in A5. I'm currently using VBA for that but a formula idea would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I put the formula in every row of Column D. It will only display in the last row of each group. That way you don't need to worry about placing it in the gaps. If you want it in the gaps, you need to modify the formula somewhat. to account for being in Col A rather than Col D. And remove the IF() at the start of the formula.